# building circular graphic for angles in degrees

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graphics, angle

I have a data of turning angles for a group of animals separated by occupation areas (breeding ground, migratory route, feeding area).

I need to plot a circular graphic in R for angle values in degrees for each area.

The angle values are like that in the data frame

```
 [1]       NA   41.027  -43.410   29.056   18.241   -7.125   -4.702    0.298
   [9]   37.846   -7.545  -69.403   -7.376   17.289    7.927   60.752  -85.219
  [17]   24.218  -17.482    3.703   -3.901   -8.582  -84.871   38.448   44.028
  [25] -150.796  -59.679 -169.927   -6.862   51.130   -1.784  -16.468   -2.356
  [33]    5.645   -6.988    4.750   -5.707    2.949   -6.150   -4.129    0.869
  [41]   -1.935    5.130    0.559    4.686  145.086   14.324 -169.206    1.741
  [49]   53.595   15.315   36.892   49.279   21.171   10.739  122.553 -141.081
  [57]    3.126   48.323   -7.139  163.742  141.473   47.320  128.430  175.918
  [65]    7.447  -16.159   55.957   37.351   -2.703  -25.308  -31.338       NA
  [73]       NA  -16.028   25.110  -31.085  -92.887   88.917  146.903 -148.539
  [81]  -11.576   41.030 -155.616 -129.368  -32.886 -164.284 -120.785  118.591
  [89]   68.335  -98.038   40.347  166.333   19.495 -170.337 -178.322   99.111
```

can someone help me with this simple question? thank u!

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you want, but here are two visualizations that might help.  The first just plots points on the unit circle to show the angles. The second version has lines in the directions of turn.   BTW, I simply left out your NAs.

Data at the bottom

```
x = cos(pi*Turns/180)
y = sin(pi*Turns/180)

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
plot(x,y, pch=20, col="#22222266", asp=1)
plot(x,y, pch=20, col="#22222266", asp=1)
N = length(x)
segments(0, 0, x, y)
```

[image: Angle plot]

Data

```
Turns = c(41.027  -43.410, 29.056, 18.241, -7.125, -4.702,  0.298, 
    37.846, -7.545  -69.403, -7.376, 17.289,  7.927, 60.752  -85.219,
  24.218,  -17.482,  3.703, -3.901, -8.582  -84.871, 38.448, 44.028,
  -150.796,  -59.679 -169.927, -6.862, 51.130, -1.784  -16.468, -2.356,
  5.645, -6.988,  4.750, -5.707,  2.949, -6.150, -4.129,  0.869,
  -1.935,  5.130,  0.559,  4.686,  145.086, 14.324 -169.206,  1.741,
   53.595, 15.315, 36.892, 49.279, 21.171, 10.739,  122.553, -141.081,
  3.126, 48.323, -7.139,  163.742,  141.473, 47.320,  128.430,  175.918,
  7.447,  -16.159, 55.957, 37.351, -2.703  -25.308,  -31.338,
  -16.028, 25.110,  -31.085,  -92.887, 88.917,  146.903, -148.539,
  -11.576, 41.030, -155.616, -129.368,  -32.886, -164.284, -120.785,  118.591,
  68.335,  -98.038, 40.347,  166.333, 19.495, -170.337, -178.322, 99.111)
```